# Why can't I set the x11-keymap to us-mac on centos?

Tags: centos

I am trying to set the x11-keymap (the console keymap already works) using localectl like this...

```
localectl set-x11-keymap us-mac
```

but I get

```
Failed to set keymap: Specified keymap cannot be compiled, refusing as invalid.
```

Again it worked for

```
localectl set-keymap us-mac
```